# jqgrid is not loading data

Tags: php, jquery, json, jqgrid

**i have following files.this file contains html code only:-**

***jqgrid.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jq_grid/css/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jq_grid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

        <script src="js/jquery 1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jq_grid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jq_grid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/accounts.js"> </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="list2"></table>
        <div id="pager2"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

***accounts.js***
    *this fille contains jquery code*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'http://localhost/property%20guruji/handler/admin/hadler.accounts.php?q=2',
    dataType: "json",
    mtype:"GET",
    colNames:['Id','Username', 'Email', 'Created On'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'username',index:'username', width:90},
        {name:'email',index:'email', width:100},
        {name:'createdon',index:'createdon', width:80, align:"right"},

    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example"
});
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

});
```

and i have the file which provide json data

```
{"page":"1","total":1,"records":5,"rows":[{"id":10,"cell":[10,"vikas","vil@gmail.com","24\/02\/2013"]},{"id":9,"cell":[9,"kaml","kamal@yahoo.in","02\/02\/2013"]},{"id":6,"cell":[6,"jkdfjdkjfkdjf","djfk@yahoo.com","02\/02\/2013"]},{"id":5,"cell":[5,"avdd","email","02\/02\/2013"]},{"id":1,"cell":[1,"admin","admin",""]}]}
```

its loading the file but no data is shown.

thanks in advance

Comment: Verify jQuery file name, remove space: `js/jquery[SPACE]1.8.0.js`. This is not the solution, but a tip.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why are u calling jqGrid twice? Do you see an error in the is console?

Comment: jg_grid is my folder name.I am not getting any error in console thats why i so much confused

Answer (score 0):

I wonder about your JSON.  Why is the id not inside cell? While it is legitimate JSON structure it would be different then the JSON structure in one of my grids.

Example jqGrid JSON

```
{"total":11,"page":1,"records":109,"rows":[{"cell":["243","3/10/2013 9:28 PM","243","username","0.00" ...
```